# Is it possible to make a DLL plugin for EditPlus to extend the editor like in EditPlug or Notepad++?

Tags: editplus

Is it possible to make a DLL plugin for the programming editor called EditPlus?

I wish to extend the editor like in EditPlug text editor or Notepad++ where you create a DLL which allows you to talk to the editor.  Or another example is Total Commander where you create a DLL to talk to the program from your own code in delphi or visual c++, or any program that can create a windows DLL.

Or is there NO way to make a plugin in Editplus because they have not implemented a plugin system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any kind of plugin architecture mentioned in EditPlus's [feature list](https://www.editplus.com/summary.html).  If it does not expose a plugin API, then you cannot write a plugin for it.  All you can do is create a DLL that is injected into EditPlus's address space by an external process and then uses OS API calls to directly manipulate EditPlus's UI and raw memory as needed.

Answer (score 1):

EditPlus does not have a plugin system, so you cannot extend in any way.

Answer (score 0):

[EditPlus](http://www.editplus.com/) has no plugin system!

In EditPlus, You can only use Text Filter to do something like plugins do.

Text Filter can execute script file or executable file.
You can use perl, java, python, vbscript, javascript or command line application which support standard input and standard output to write and run as a text filter.

Text Filter only can change the text content in the editor area.

I'll be very glad if a real plugin system come with EditPlus.

See also:

[Writing a text filter for EditPlus](http://editplus.info/wiki/Writing_a_text_filter)

[Some Text Filters for EditPlus](http://www.editplus.com/filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. it's hard (..not so very hard..but still) 
i explain in here the possibility to extend Editplus with php

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61254718/5781320

i see this cause i lookin' for other simplest methods than mine.(just by curiosity and fun) .. i wrote the fastest php framework in the world and I will glad to make it "talk" with editplus

There is possible to compile servers in PUREBASIC.com to interact with  applications Android in b4a=open source now (b4x.com) that suppose to interact with google speech recognition so yes is possible to talk from your phone to the server dll or exe to interact with editplus,total commander,and many other stuff.
I did it myself cause i was curious if had delay.
EditPlus hasn't the direct possibility , Notepad++ does and on https://www.purebasic.fr/english/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=65680&hilit=notepad+plugin with the same purebasic i use on that notepad++ version work that pugin can be modiffied  how you like to be .On actual version of notepad++ i tryed myself doesn't work : the plugin is obsolete and is rejected so witch method you choose is hard to implement the system you need int this dynamic expansion of open source / or developing.